# Unable to boot Yosemite and old system after Upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, macos, kernel-panic, kernel-extensions

I have upgraded my MBP 5,1 (2,53 GHz) from Snow Leopard to Yosemite. The install went terribly wrong and now neither a fresh Yosemite, nor a fresh Snow Leopard would boot.

Moving away /System/Library/Extensions/NVDAResmanTesla.kext in Yosemite or NVDAResman.kext in Snow Leopard makes the system bootable.

Howver, the graphics under Yosemite are extremely slow and full of artifacts withot this kext, so this is no solution.

These are the graphic cards: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M and 9600M GT.

I am completely lost why this problem can persist fresh installs even of the old OS X version. I have also reset the NVRAM and SMC. What else could the Yosemite install have changed?

I think it's very unlikely that my graphics card went kaputt just at the same time...

Also, the SSD (OWC Mercury EXTREME Pro SSD, 361A13F0) passed all checks.
The only other modification to the system is that I don't have an internal DVD drive anymore. The slot is empty.

Here's the content of the kernel panic log:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801201e80a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f941ff483, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000010, CR3: 0x0000000110b30000, CR4: 0x0000000000002660
RAX: 0x66bc590a0c430001, RBX: 0xffffff8075915000, RCX: 0xffffff809d785000, RDX: 0xffffff80a414b908
RSP: 0xffffff80a414bac0, RBP: 0xffffff80a414bac0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x0000000000004311, R9:  0xffffff8022980888, R10: 0xffffff801bd33d80, R11: 0x000000000000002c
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff8029c54000, R14: 0xffffff8075915000, R15: 0xffffff8075915000
RFL: 0x0000000000010293, RIP: 0xffffff7f941ff483, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000010, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1


Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a414b770 : 0xffffff8011f3a811
0xffffff80a414b7f0 : 0xffffff801201e80a
0xffffff80a414b9b0 : 0xffffff801203a443
0xffffff80a414b9d0 : 0xffffff7f941ff483
0xffffff80a414bac0 : 0xffffff7f941e892a
0xffffff80a414bb10 : 0xffffff7f941e8878
0xffffff80a414bb30 : 0xffffff7f941c4116
0xffffff80a414bb70 : 0xffffff7f936d46df
0xffffff80a414bbc0 : 0xffffff7f936d45f2
0xffffff80a414bbe0 : 0xffffff7f936d890a
0xffffff80a414bc70 : 0xffffff7f936d08ac
0xffffff80a414bcb0 : 0xffffff7f93cb0fe8
0xffffff80a414bd00 : 0xffffff80124b85b1
0xffffff80a414bd50 : 0xffffff80124ff0b5
0xffffff80a414bdc0 : 0xffffff8011fea95e
0xffffff80a414be10 : 0xffffff8011f3e91c
0xffffff80a414be40 : 0xffffff8011f235a3
0xffffff80a414be90 : 0xffffff8011f33e8d
0xffffff80a414bf10 : 0xffffff801200a142
0xffffff80a414bfb0 : 0xffffff801203ac66
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0 xffffff7f936c6000->0xffffff7f936fffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff 7f92724000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28 EE2B]@0xffffff7f93cad000->0xffffff7f93f15fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff 7f92724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xff ffff7f93a42000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0 xffffff7f936c6000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[67CD214F-0F26-3BEF-BAD0-CF0F83C2616D]@0xffffff7f94 1c0000->0xffffff7f9428dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff 7f92724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xff ffff7f93a42000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0 xffffff7f936c6000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA 28EE2B]@0xffffff7f93cad000


BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: -v


Mac OS version:
14A389


Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000011c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011d00000
System model name: MacBookPro5,1 (Mac-F42D86C8)


System uptime in nanoseconds: 43229767838
last loaded kext at 41177702061: com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f942e8000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver 1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.37
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124
com.apple.GeForceTesla 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.4d1
com.apple.nvenet 2.0.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 800.20.24
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.10
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup 10.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI 656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 161
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 97
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.7.21
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla 10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 700.52
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
com.apple.driver.NVSMU 2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm 1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
```

Any ideas what is causing this and what I can do?

Comment: Yosemite doesn't allow custom kexts any more, unless you flip a switch - details here http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have not installed any custom kexts as far as I know. What makes you think I did?

Comment: Only that the largest number of Google hits for that kext are on sites like TonyMac etc.. I was just adding 1 & 1 & maybe getting 3 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Fresh install from tiger then upgrade until the last OS X supported on your Mac

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yosemite supports MBP 2007+ and mine is late 2008. What is the benefit of starting with Tiger instead of starting with either Yosemite or Snow Leopard, like I did?